# R gbm logistic regression

Tags: r

I was hoping to use the `GBM` package to do logistic regression, but it is giving answers slightly outside of the 0-1 range.  I've tried the suggested distribution parameters for 0-1 predictions (`bernoulli`, and `adaboost`) but that actually makes things worse than using `gaussian`.

```
GBM_NTREES = 150
GBM_SHRINKAGE = 0.1
GBM_DEPTH = 4
GBM_MINOBS = 50
> GBM_model <- gbm.fit(
+ x = trainDescr 
+ ,y = trainClass 
+ ,distribution = "gaussian"
+ ,n.trees = GBM_NTREES
+ ,shrinkage = GBM_SHRINKAGE
+ ,interaction.depth = GBM_DEPTH
+ ,n.minobsinnode = GBM_MINOBS
+ ,verbose = TRUE)
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1        0.0603             nan     0.1000    0.0019
     2        0.0588             nan     0.1000    0.0016
     3        0.0575             nan     0.1000    0.0013
     4        0.0563             nan     0.1000    0.0011
     5        0.0553             nan     0.1000    0.0010
     6        0.0546             nan     0.1000    0.0008
     7        0.0539             nan     0.1000    0.0007
     8        0.0533             nan     0.1000    0.0006
     9        0.0528             nan     0.1000    0.0005
    10        0.0524             nan     0.1000    0.0004
   100        0.0484             nan     0.1000    0.0000
   150        0.0481             nan     0.1000   -0.0000
> prediction <- predict.gbm(object = GBM_model
+ ,newdata = testDescr
+ ,GBM_NTREES)
> hist(prediction)
> range(prediction)
[1] -0.02945224  1.00706700
```

Bernoulli:

```
GBM_model <- gbm.fit(
x = trainDescr 
,y = trainClass 
,distribution = "bernoulli"
,n.trees = GBM_NTREES
,shrinkage = GBM_SHRINKAGE
,interaction.depth = GBM_DEPTH
,n.minobsinnode = GBM_MINOBS
,verbose = TRUE)
prediction <- predict.gbm(object = GBM_model
+ ,newdata = testDescr
+ ,GBM_NTREES)
> hist(prediction)
> range(prediction)
[1] -4.699324  3.043440
```

And adaboost:

```
GBM_model <- gbm.fit(
x = trainDescr 
,y = trainClass 
,distribution = "adaboost"
,n.trees = GBM_NTREES
,shrinkage = GBM_SHRINKAGE
,interaction.depth = GBM_DEPTH
,n.minobsinnode = GBM_MINOBS
,verbose = TRUE)
> prediction <- predict.gbm(object = GBM_model
+ ,newdata = testDescr
+ ,GBM_NTREES)
> hist(prediction)
> range(prediction)
[1] -3.0374228  0.9323279
```

Am I doing something wrong, do I need to preProcess (scale, center) the data or do I need to go in and manually floor/cap the values with something like :

```
prediction <- ifelse(prediction < 0, 0, prediction)
prediction <- ifelse(prediction > 1, 1, prediction)
```

Comment: Care to share your data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `?predict.gbm`:

> Returns a vector of predictions. By default the predictions are on the scale of f(x). For example,
>   for the Bernoulli loss the returned value is on the log odds scale, poisson loss on the log scale, and
>   coxph is on the log hazard scale.
>
> If type="response" then gbm converts back to the same scale as the outcome. Currently the only
>   effect this will have is returning probabilities for bernoulli and expected counts for poisson. For the
>   other distributions "response" and "link" return the same.

So if you use `distribution="bernoulli"`, you need to transform the predicted values to rescale them to [0, 1]: `p <- plogis(predict.gbm(model))`. Using `distribution="gaussian"` is really for regression as opposed to classification, although I'm surprised that the predictions aren't in [0, 1]: my understanding is that gbm is still based on trees, so the predicted values shouldn't be able to go outside the values present in the training data.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change the 'type=' argument to 'response' in predict.gbm().